# A rigidbody object fall thru other other objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a rigidbody object in unity, that falls thru other objects. I added a mesh collider but it's still doesn't works. What do I need to do?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. It has nothing to do with [tag:unity-container]. This is an invalid use of the [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get it working, ensure that:

- Both objects have a collider (like a box collider, mesh collider or sphere collider)
- No collider has `Is Trigger` checked
- In Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics, the two object layers aren't unticked in the Layer Collision Matrix
- Nowhere in your code do you disable collisions of the two object layers via `Physics.IgnoreCollision`
- If objects move at high speed, you use a `Continuous` type in the Rigidbody's Collision Detection dropdown
- All the collider meshes are appropriate as to what your mesh filter looks like (they may have a different mesh), e.g. not contain holes; turn on all gizmos so you can see what the collision mesh looks like in green wireframe
- The collider meshes are not changed in Center or Size so as to make them missable
- There's no error message "Non-convex MeshCollider with non-kinematic Rigidbody is no longer supported since Unity 5"; tick `Convex` on the Mesh Collider if so
- There's not any other error messages

Good luck!