# How to add components to GameObject via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently in the early stages of making a game. I have developed a procedural generated mesh. The next thing I need to do is somehow in the script, add some type of collider. I believe I would need to use AddComponent in some way but this is not working. When I put **mesh.AddComponent** I get a error saying *Mesh does not contain a definition for 'AddComponent'*. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: what is "mesh" as a variable, whatever you add that mesh to, you want to add (probably a mesh collider) to that.. as well as the mesh

Answer (score 2):

To add a collider dynamically, don't use mesh.AddComponent, but

```
MeshCollider collider = mesh.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
// Now you can toggle options of that collider, like by doing
collider.convex = true;
```

If your script is attached to the respective gameObject, you can also just use `gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>()`. (Be aware that when the object also uses a non-kinematic rigidbody, your collider must use `convex` to work.)

Comment: My object still falls through the mesh that I have created

Comment: I now have a mesh collider on my mesh, and a sphere collider on the object on top of the mesh. But the object still falls through. I have the mesh collider in the start function of my mesh generator class.

Comment: @TylerThompson [Here are some typical causes of that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60028644/34170). Good luck!